# asp.net mvc optional params in razor actionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, optional-parameters

I have 2 links for language switch

```
<a class="dropdown-item"               
    href="@Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "en" }, null)" 
    style="color:#333;">English</a>

<a class="dropdown-item"                                      
    href="@Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "ar" }, null)" 
    style="color:#333;">Arabic</a>
```

it works fine there is only controller and action in url
but when there is optional param like id for detail and edit action than it do not work as expected.

I think I have to change null (this last param) with something but I am new and googled a lot but not getting anything worthy, Please help me.

It would be better if the solution work for n number of optional params instead of only one `Id`, but for now that will also be acceptable.

Comment: The last argument (`null`) is for adding html attributes. You need to add additional parameters to the 4th argument - e.g. `new { language = "en", id = someValue }`

Comment: Thank u @stephen Can you please help me with id = what? in case `products/edit/12` and `products/detail/12`

Comment: I did it, by `new { language = "en", id = ViewContext.RouterData.Values["id"] }` is this optimal and error free in all cases

Comment: Why don't you use Html.Action or Html.RenderAction?

Answer (score 0):

**it would be better if the solution work for n number of optional params instead of only one Id**

for getting all passed querystring parameter on MVC controller side better to use

```
Request.QueryString
```

Request.QueryString is NameValueCollection and you get value passed in querystring parameter in your actionlink.

i have tried that looks like below

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),  new { language = "ar",id="100",studentid = 1,studentName = "abc" }, null)" style="color:#333;">Arabic</a>
```

and your mvc Controller look like below

```
public ActionResult About(int id)
{
      var querystring = Request.QueryString;
       // in querystring you get all value like below screenshot
       var studentName = querystring["studentName"]; // access parameter like 
      ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

      return View();
}
```

you can get all parameter that you passed in your controller.
[image]